# Make nodes appear as points with outside label

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using TikZ to draw a pretty large diagram, with the points generated from a csv file. (A Python script gets the coordinates from the csv, and outputs a corresponding node line.) A minimal example would be this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (1,3) {A};
\node (B) at (1,1) {B};
\draw (A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces something like this:

[image: With TikZ]

How do I make it look more like the following (ignore the uppercase/lowercase difference):

[image: With graphviz -- the label is outside and the node is marked as a dot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to automatize this a bit, here's a solution:

[image: nodes as points]

Use `label distance` to put away your labels as you want and set the nodes appearance accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        label distance=2pt,
        every node/.style={
            draw,
            fill=black,
            circle,
            inner sep=0pt,
            minimum size=3pt}]
        \node[label=above left:a] (A) at (1,3) {};
        \node[label=above left:b] (B) at (1,1) {};
        \draw (A) -- (B);   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use a node of shape `circle`.
2. Put a [label](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#tikz/label) on that node (which is just another node that references the position of the parent node).
3. Connect the nodes, TikZ automatically chooses their borders.

(The [`inner sep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/inner:sep) specifies a radius that is multiplied by √2 to get to the actual radius – it calculates a radius around a square with sides of length 2× inner sep. A [`minimum size`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/minimum:size) specifies the diameter of the circle.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={shape=circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+1.5pt}]
\node[dot, label=above left:a] (A) at (1,3) {};
\node[dot, label=above left:b] (B) at (1,1) {};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={
    shape=circle, fill, draw, inner sep=+1.5pt,
    name={#1}, label={$#1$}, node contents=},
  label position=above left]
\node at (1,3) [dot=a];
\node at (1,1) [dot=b];
\draw (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

voila, just use the label

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[label={[left]:a},inner sep=0] (A) at (1,3) {$\bullet$};
\node[label={[left]:b},inner sep=0]  (B) at (1,1) {$\bullet$};
\draw(A) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is some gap between the dot for a and the line?

Comment: It should be `label={left:a}`, not `label={[left]:a}`. To get rid of the gap, try `\draw(A.center) -- (B.center);`